# How to get a favicon to display in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, favicon

The favicon on my website in favicon.ico format did not appear in IE and firefox( when the site was reloaded after using favicon). It is appearing in chrome and in firefox of another computer where the site was opened for the first time.

Again , when I have restarted system, it is appearing in firefox, but no luck with IE. The webpages are .aspx pages. How to make the favicon appear on IE?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post up any relevant code.

Comment: Also consider providing a link to the site in question since I can think of at least 8 reasons why it may be broken.

Comment: Hi, The url is [link](http://assignmentdesign.com)

Comment: I have the below code in master page:<link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />